# "Property [titulo] does not exist on this collection instance" error on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've been stuck with this error for two days, here's the thing. I'm trying to show an specific chapter of a online course, meaning that, I have a view that show me the list of chapters and everytime I click in one of them it sends me to the specific chapter that I just clicked on, the controller of that specific view it's done

```
 public function show_capitulos($id)
{$data=Capitulo::select('capitulos.titulo','capitulos.descripcion','capitulo_secciones.contenido','capitulo_videos.video')
    ->join('capitulo_secciones','capitulos.id','=','capitulo_secciones.capitulo_id')
    ->join('capitulo_videos','capitulos.id','=','capitulo_secciones.capitulo_id')
    ->where('capitulos.id',$id)
    ->get();
     return view('alumno.capitulos_curso')->with(['data'=>$data]);}
```

I've read a lot of blogs and questions with this error, and trust me I've tried everything but I can seem to catch the mistake.

This is what I have in my view

```
 <h1 class="nombre-capitulo">{{ $data->titulo}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` returns a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) of all of the models that satisfy the query. You could use `first()` instead to only retrieve a single model. Simple change `get()` to `first()` in your code snippet. You can read more about retrieving results from eloquent queries [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results).

Comment: If I change that part I get this error **Trying to get property 'titulo' of non-object**

Comment: Then it sounds like the result of the query is `null`.

Comment: I checked the database and it has data, it's weird that it's returning null, for what I checked there's no error in the controller

Comment: Try using `php artisan tinker` to debug your query.

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is a collection not a single record so you have to use a loop. For example:

```
@foreach($data as $singleData)
    <h1 class="nombre-capitulo">{{ $singleData->titulo}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need only a single record

Comment: If you need a single record you have to change your query and replace the `get()` in the end with `first()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all result form collection then you have loop on collection.

```
@foreach($data as $d)
      <h1 class="nombre-capitulo">{{ $d->titulo}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps :)